# Why should I choose Xeon or Epic when Ryzen are way faster?

Tags: hardware, central-processing-unit, xeon

I'm selecting 2 servers to run a world-facing web application for a customer. One will host the web server, the other the DB.

I can choose between Xeon and Ryzen CPUs and.. oh, my! Xeons are [way more expensive and apparently way slower](https://www.cpubenchmark.net/compare/5127vs4462vs4407vs5036vs5031/Intel-Xeon-E-2324G-vs-Intel-Xeon-Silver-4309Y-vs-AMD-EPYC-7313P-vs-AMD-Ryzen-7-7700X-vs-AMD-Ryzen-9-7950X). **Why would someone choose the former over the latter?**

Yes, I know that Xeon officially support EEC RAM while Ryzen support in unofficial, but, still, I don't feel comfortable recommending a CPU with a 25-40% lower single-thread rating at double the price.

Also: I know that consumer CPUs max out at 16 cores / 32 threads while some Xeon go beyond that, but for the specific use case 16c/32t are more than enough.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 3):

That's because Ryzen's aren't server processors, they're for desktops/laptops - this is like comparing a Mac Truck with a Hyundai hatchback - they're designed for different tasks. It's comparing apples to oranges.

Try comparing a Xeon to an AMD EPYC - that's comparing apples to apples.

Also try to use production-grade kit for production, using consumer stuff as servers works, I do it for my home lab, but don't bet your job, and the reputation of your organisation on it.

Also product recommendations aren't on topic here - it's in the help pages - so I'd imagine this question will be closed shortly.